# First value in server side <select> always submitted to db regardless of user selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having a problem where no matter what value the user has selected in the HtmlSelect control 'drpTeam', the first value in the list (57) is sent to the db. This only occurs in one of our two testing environments. It doesn't happen in my local dev machine.

I've checked the client side value of the select control through IE's dev tools and it shows the correct selected value. However, when clicking the submit button, it always submits 57 (the first entry in the select control  list). I used fiddler to confirm that IE is sending the correct value, eg. 61. I used SQL Profiler to check what value SQL Server is receiving from entity framework and it is 57. So the problem isn't in the db. I can't step through the aspx.cs code as this is occurring in a testing environment. Somehow, regardless of what value IE sends to the webserver, the webserver always replaces it with 57.

drpTeam is defined as:

```
<select id="drpTeam" runat="server" onchange="drpConfirmationTeam_SelectedIndexChanged(0);"></select>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="drpTeam" CssClass="style1" ErrorMessage="(*)"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

The problem occurs regardless of whether or not `drpConfirmationTeam_SelectedIndexChanged(0)` is ever called, so the problem is not in that function.

The HTML generated by the aspx page for drpTeam looks like this:

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$drpTeam" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drpTeam" Validators="[object HTMLSpanElement]">
<option value="57">
TeamA
</option>
<option value="58">
TeamB
</option>
<option value="59">
TeamC
</option>
...
</select>
```

Code for submit button click event is below:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var db = new EFDBContext())
    {
        User user = null;
        int userID = Convert.ToInt32(hdnUserID.Value);
        int profileChangeRequestID = Convert.ToInt32(hdnPCRID.Value);
        int actionerUserID = db.Users.Single(u => u.NTID == User.Identity.Name).UserID;
        user = (hdnUserID.Value == "0") ? new User() : db.Users.Single(u => u.UserID == userID);

        user.Name = txtName.Text;
        user.NTID = txtNTID.Text;
        user.RoleID = Convert.ToInt32(drpRole.SelectedValue);

//Error happens in below line:

        user.TeamID = Convert.ToInt32(drpTeam.Value); // Always submits 57 (first <option>) for drpTeam.Value

//Error happens in above line^^^^^^

        if (drpGroup.SelectedIndex != 0 && drpGroup.SelectedIndex != -1)
            user.GroupID = Convert.ToInt32(drpGroup.SelectedValue);
        else
            user.GroupID = null;

        user.Transit = txtTransit.Text;
        user.Location = "";
        user.FaxNumber = txtFax.Text;
        user.Email = txtEmail.Text;
        user.PhoneNumber = txtPhoneNumber.Text;
        user.Title = txtTitle.Text;
        user.ReceiveEmails = chkReceiveEmails.Checked;

        user.ReportsToUserID = (drpReportsTo.SelectedIndex != 0) ? (int?)Int32.Parse(drpReportsTo.SelectedValue) : null;
        user.isActive = true;

        if (hdnUserID.Value == "0")
            db.Users.Add(user);

        ProfileChangeRequest profileChangeRequest =
            db.ProfileChangeRequests.Single(pcr => pcr.ProfileChangeRequestID == profileChangeRequestID);

        db.ProfileChangeRequests.Remove(profileChangeRequest);

        db.SaveChanges();

        bindGrid();

        divUserFormConfirm.Style.Add("display", "none");
        divConfirmationSuccess.Style.Add("display", "inline");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be `drpTeam.SelectedValue` not `drpTeam.Value`.  No idea why your local dev env doesn't have the same problem.

Comment: I thought so too. But apparently SelectedValue only applies to <asp:DropDownList> types. Since this DDL is defined as a <select> with a runat="server" tag, the only option is .value. On my dev machine the .value property returns the correctly selected value.